# JavaFX Webview shows map too small

Tags: webview, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application that contains a WebView in which an OpenStreetMap is displayed, you can zoom and scroll, add an overlay and draw little dots on it, it's been running on all systems (win, mac, linux) and on various hardware setups (desktops and notebooks). It's marvellous.

But now I had a friend of mine drop by with his notebook, we installed it and I was quite baffled to see that the map is only displayed as a small square in the upper-left corner, the overlay and drawing functionality is all fine and as big as it should be.

I have been on this for a few days now and I was unable to reproduce the error on other systems, just as I was unable to fix it on my friend's notebook. We even found someone with the same notebook model, but the error did not occur on that one.

So my ideas are basically done and I don't even have an idea on how this error comes to be.

Has someone who reads this experienced similar errors or has an idea on how this happens? Could there be system-specific settings (environment variables, registry etc.) that might cause side-effects like this?

Comment: Did you check and compare the JRE and JavaFX versions? I had some problems in the past with the WebView component some JavaFX versions that were known bugs, and some of them occured only on special platforms.

Comment: What OS do you run on the notebook?

Comment: A JRE that is used by the application is provided with the installer, the operating system is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked if windows does some optimizations?
There is some sort of "Enlarge Text" Option in the display settings and on notebooks it's usually set to 125% or 150% textsize. Maybe that has some weird sideeffects.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was indeed the solution. Apparently the WebView is not affected by certain resolution optimizations done by windows.